# Crashes with black screen

Tags: 20.04, amd-graphics, crash

Laptop HP 15-eh1* Ryzen 7 5700u crashes with black screen. This happens randomly when browsing or watching videos. It can be reproduced using the app Digikam->image processing ->enhancement->sharpen. When trying the sharpening laptop freezes immediately.
No log entries with relation to this error (dmesg, journalctl).
Video card driver(integrated gpu) is driver=amdgpu
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS, kernel 5.15.0-60-generic.

Hints about how to check some other logs or debug the problem would be nice too.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu and what driver are you using for the video card?

Comment: @David, Video card driver(integrated gpu) is driver=amdgpu
Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS. I'll update my question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm too late, but I have been searching for a solution to AMD GPUs crashing on Linux for a week now, and I may have finally found a solution for my case.

Disable HW acceleration in Firefox/Chrome/Discord and any other programs that use it.

You wouldn't believe how many massive things I attempted to fix this problem, like uninstalling open source drivers or upgrading/downgrading kernel or formatting and fresh installing a new version of Ubuntu. It is wild to me that this fixed all my issues instantly and that I would find absolutely nothing about it whenever I googled it.